# Match column value and values in a python list

Tags: python, sqlite

I want to copy all values that has an ID that is contained in a python list into a new table in SQLite like this:

`cur.execute("INSERT INTO newtable SELECT * FROM oldtable where userid IN " + userids)`

Userids is a list that comes from a file:

`userids = [line.strip() for line in open('inputfile.txt')]`

But I get the following error:
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects

And I have the growing suspicion that this list with about 15000 elements would be too long for the query as well(?). How would I do this without querying once for each id in the list?

Comment: maybe join the contents `" ".join(userids )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

join the list in a string.

```
userIdsStr = ', '.join(userids)
```

Then do something like:

```
cur.execute('INSERT INTO newtable SELECT * FROM oldtable where userid IN (%s)' % userIdsStr)
```

I hope this helps